# Tensorflow Object Detection API - Do something when an object is detected

Tags: object, tensorflow, detection

Hi I'm currently searching for studies or tutorials where they used tensorflow API to do something (alarm, save video, print something, etc.) when a certain object is detected. I don't know if I'm bad at using google cause I can't seem to find what I want. Hope you guys can give me links regarding this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

go into the visualize_utils.py in the utils folder under the current model directory and start tweaking with it.

if you want to tweak with perse print something if you detect an object whose label is already known, you may want to do the following under

```
def visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(.....):
```

Say if you want to print the current object to python command line modify the following section of above mention method as follows

```
  else:
    if not agnostic_mode:
      if classes[i] in category_index.keys():
        class_name = category_index[classes[i]]['name']
        if (class_name == 'person'):
          print(class_name + "Detected")
```

Please correct me / add upon to my answer ! Thanks and Welcome in advance!

Comment: So you want to trigger an event that sends you an email when a dog is detected taking a crap on your lawn?

I agreed with the previous comment as well,I have done similar things, where I have actually wrote my own visualize_utils.py to trigger an event when an object was detected. I have done a couple where I trigger an HTTP post request. from here your options are endless.

Comment: That'd be nice if you can share with us that version of visualize_utils.py!Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The method ***[draw_bounding_box_on_image](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py)*** - [Line 131](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/95385809e79369337e5431f3e778700a77dc93a9/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py#L131) which draws bounding box for each detected object. You can call another methods to manipulate the detected object etc. inside of draw_bounding_box_on_image method.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/

here you go

This will help i guess